# Как кастомизировать TitleBar при MainActivity extends FragmentActivity Android

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, android-layout

Проблема c кастомизацией `TitleBar` из-за наследования главного класса от `FragmentActivity`. На выходе мне нужно получить статичный `title` из своего `layout_title.xml` не изменяемый во время слайда по фрагментам. При попытке сборки возникают ошибки на строке `RequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);`
Точнее вот это:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.***.***/com.***.***.MainActivity}:
>   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called
>   before adding conten

Пробовал в MyTheme удалять строчку:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Мой код:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_min);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); //сюда идет ругань
    this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);

    FragmentAdapter titleAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    settings.setTitles(getString(R.string.text_save), getString(R.string.text_get), getString(R.string.text_help));
}
```

AndroidManifest кусок:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

MyTheme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/AppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requestFeature() must be called before adding conten` переводится как `requestFeature() нужно вызывать до того, как добавлять контент`. Это значит - `до setContentView()`.

Перенесите строку

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

сразу после

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все получилось.

Comment: Если ответ правильный, то отметьте его, как правильный